# S3 delete versioned objects with DeleteMarker

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I have to delete S3 versioned objects that have a DeleteMarker after the first delete operation:

```
{ DeleteMarker: true, VersionId: 'TxxQ.AtCmKflgRz6xTeBVYdOeTTLKUt' }
```

For this reason, as suggested in the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeleteMarker.html)

I try to delete the object specifying the delete marker version id, but I then get another response as above:

```
{ DeleteMarker: true, VersionId: 'TxxQ.AtCmKflgRz6xTeBVYdOeTTLKUt' }
```

The whole code is the following:

```
        var s3 = self.s3Store.GetInstance();
        var params = { 
            Bucket: options.Bucket,
            Key: documentKey 
        };
        if (self.logger) self.logger.info("S3Dataset delete bucket:%s key:%s", options.Bucket, documentKey);
        s3.deleteObject(params, function (error, data) {
            if (error) {
                if (self.logger) self.logger.error("S3Dataset delete error key:%s error:%@", documentKey, error);
                return callback(error);
            }
            else if (!Util.empty(data) &&
                !Util.empty(data) &&
                data.DeleteMarker &&
                !Util.empty(data.VersionId)) { // object version to delete

                var VersionId = data.VersionId;
                // The bucket is versioned - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeleteMarker.html
                // { "DeleteMarker": true, "VersionId": "azW0.aiZyTSQzjwFe0YkIkGyL.JXJK8y" }
                if (self.logger) self.logger.info("S3Dataset delete key:%s version:%@", documentKey, VersionId);

                var params = { 
                    Bucket: options.Bucket,
                    Key: documentKey,
                    VersionId: VersionId
                };
                s3.deleteObject(params, function (error, data) {
                    if (error) {
                        if (self.logger) self.logger.error("S3Dataset delete error key:%s error:%@", documentKey, error);
                        return callback(error);
                    } else {
                        return callback(null,data);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                var error = new Error('delete error');
                if (self.logger) self.logger.error("S3Dataset delete error key:%s error:%@", documentKey, error);
                return callback(error);
            }
```

The result is another response with `VersionId`:

```
{
   "DeleteMarker": true,
   "VersionId": "TxxQ.AtCmKflgRz6xTeBVYdOeTTLKUt"
}
```

So it seems the actual deletion is not happening, despite using deletion with `VersionID` for that object.

If I do the same in `Python`

```
import boto3

BUCKET = 'my_buckt'
key = 'my_bucket_key'
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.delete_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=key)
```

it works (file deleted) without any versioning support.